# Geometric series - regarding the exponents of the factor r

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

When giving a proof for the formula of a geometric sum, the following sequence is used
$$S = a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^{n-1},$$
Why does the last term go to $n-1$ and not just $n$? I wrote the last term as $ar^n$ but that would give me the following formula 
$$S = a\frac{r^{n+1} - 1}{r-1}.$$

Comment: Basically, the formula is stated in this way because $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}$ is a sum of exactly $n$ terms.  You could just as easily have preferred to state the formula for $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n$, favoring having final exponent $n$ instead of $n$ terms.

Comment: How do you see that it is exactly n terms? And favoring a final exponent n, doesnt that imply n terms?

Comment: $a=ar^0$ is the first term, so $ar^1$ is the second term, ... so $ar^{n-1}$ is the $n$th term.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S=a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^m$$ where $r\ne1$

$$\implies aS=ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^m+ar^{m+1}$$

On subtraction we have $$S(1-a)=a-ar^{m+1}=a(1-r^{m+1})$$
$$\implies S=\frac{a(1-r^{m+1})}{1-a}=\frac{a(r^{m+1}-1)}{a-1}$$

As integer $m\ge1,$ so, we can go to any number of terms

---

Alternatively, put $n-1=m$

Comment: But why do you have ar^m in your subtraction? It should disappear because S and aS both have that term

Comment: @user108090, sorry that was a terrible copy paste error

Comment: No problem! But the formula you got are precisely the one I get, is it correct?

Comment: @user108090, yes. By derivation I wanted to show that the exponent of $r$ can go to any positive integer

Answer (score 0):

Actually $ar^{n-1}$ is your nth term.

In order to obtain the formula consider the following:

let $S_n=a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^{n-1}$.

Then $rS_n=ar+ar^2+...+ar^{n-1}+ar^n$

Therefore $(1-r)S_n=a-ar^n=a(1-r^n)$.

Divide both sides by $1-r$ completes the formula.:)

Comment: Yeah, I get that! But why is n-1 my nth term?

Comment: The first term is a.
The second term is ar^1.
The third term is ar^2.
...
The n-th term will be ar^{n-1}.

Comment: For number patterns it is advisable to write out a few terms to see.:)

Comment: Yeah. If we would have labeled the a:s, that would be more obvious! Thanks bro